# How to install 'which' command on mac

Tags: macos, zsh, which

I have removed "which" command from /bin directory.

when i try to install it via Homebrew package manager, i get

> Error: No available formula for which

Comment: It's generally a very bad idea to remove commands from `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc.  If you want to use other versions, put them in `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/bin` and put that earlier on your `PATH`.

Comment: How can i install other versions?

Comment: Not trying to be snarky, but this falls into the category "if you have to ask, you probably shouldn't be messing with it."

Comment: i have tried to install it via Homebrew but the package doesn't exist for mac. read my question well.

Comment: I read your question.  My advice stands.

Comment: I don't know Homebrew, but quite likely `which` is not the name of the package (eg on Ubuntu it is part of the **debianutils** package). If you're stuck, you can always write your own script to do it: loop through the parameters with `echo $PATH|tr '\:' "\n" | while d=$(line); do if [ -x "$d/$1" ]; then echo "$d/$1"; fi; done` as the core command line. Add `break` after the `echo` command if you don't want to do `which -a`. The advice from @pjs is good, though I prefer to rename commands _in situ_, eg `mv /bin/which /bin/-which`.

Answer (score 1):

@pjs' advice is very good advice, however since the damage is already done, how can you re-install it?

1. Download the [source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-170/which/which.c)
2. Compile the program by running the following command on the commandline in directory that you downloaded which.c to: `gcc which.c -o which`
3. Copy the output file to /usr/local/bin: `cp which /usr/local/bin`